# Populating a multi (more than 2) dimensional String array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to know if there are some method / strategy to populate a multi-dimensional array.

```
private String[] MENU = {"MENU 1", "MENU 2", "MENU 3"};
private String[][][] SUBMENU = {
  {{"SUBMENU 11", "TEXTO 11"}},
{{"SUBMENU 21", "TEXTO 21"}, {"SUBMENU 22", "TEXTO 22"}},
   {{"SUBMENU 31", "TEXTO 31"}, {"SUBMENU 32", "TEXTO 32"}, {"SUBMENU 33", "TEXTO 33"}}};
```

This is an example that i obtained from here : http://www.portalandroid.org/comunidade/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=14561

But I don't know any method or way to fill that 3-dimensional String array.

Any tips?!

Comment: What do you mean? The code you posted DOES fill that 3-dimensional String array.

Comment: I guess his question was to know if there are any other ways to fill a multi-dimensional array other than the one he mentioned...and the answer is NO, except for the explicit indexing and filling mechanism.

Comment: Arham guessed! :). What i want to know is if there is /are some other methods than the one that i posted. 

I need to fill that multi-dimension array, but i don't know his size previously...

Comment: you should have framed your question accordingly by pointing out the size issue. Anyways, M M has provided a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ArrayList<String>` for the filling process, then retrieve an array by calling `String[] a1 = aList.toArray(new String[0])`, do this to all *internal* arrays, then add them all up by calling `String[][] multiDim = new String[]{a1, a2, a3, a4}`

Comment: Thank you for cooperation M.M! That suited very well.

Once again, thank you all!